# Evaluating Fibonacci-sequence-based recurrence relation (SPOJ Flibonakki)

Tags: beginner, programming-challenge, haskell, time-limit-exceeded, fibonacci-sequence

I have a function `fib2` which returning two values as Tuple but I want to print the product of tuples returned by function fib2. I am new to Haskell so please explain it to me in a simple way.

This problem is from [SPOJ](http://www.spoj.com/problems/FLIB/) which I have already solved using C and again I am trying it in Haskell:

> For each \$n\$, find \$G(n) \mod 1000000007\$, where
>   $$\begin{align*}
> G(0) &= 0 \\
> G(n) &= G(n-1) + f(4n - 1), \qquad n > 0 \\
> f(i) &= \mathrm{the\ i^{th}\ Fibobacci\ number}
> \end{align*}$$
>
> The first line of input specifies the number of test cases.

Now my code is working fine but I'm getting TLE in this problem. Can someone show me how to optimize Fibonacci in Haskell?

```
import Data.List
import Data.Maybe
import Control.Monad
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as C


fib2 0 = (1, 1)
fib2 1 = (1, 2)
fib2 n
 | even n    = ((a*a + b*b)`mod` 1000000007, (c*c - a*a)`mod` 1000000007)
 | otherwise = ((c*c - a*a)`mod` 1000000007, (b*b + c*c)`mod` 1000000007)
 where (a,b) = fib2 (n `div` 2 - 1)
       c     = a + b

solve n = (a*b)`mod`1000000007
    where (a,b) = fib2((2*n-1)`mod`2000000016)

main = C.getContents >>= putStrLn . unlines . map (show.solve.fromIntegral . fst . fromJust . C.readInteger) . tail . C.words
```

Comment: Basically, your code looks good. I get a ~25% speedup by making it a little stricter, `!c = a + b` in the `where` clause of `fib2` (requires `{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}` at the top), and a small improvement from using `quot` and `rem` instead of `div` and `mod`. I'm not sure of the compile options SPOJ passes, so adding `{-# OPTIONS_GHC -O2 #-}` after the language pragma might be required.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks for your answer. Yes I am getting compile error after changing c = a+b to !c = a + b getting Illegal bang-pattern (use -XBangPatterns). I will try to rectify this.

Comment: EDIT1:: Yes using quot and rem I got 30% speed up. But Still TLE.

Comment: You must put the language pragma at the top of the source file to use bang patterns. And have you also the optimisation pragma in the file? If SPOJ doesn't pass `-O2` as a compilation flag, you absolutely need it.

Comment: I tested my algorithm with quot and rem for another Fibonacci like problem on SPOJ. My initial AC was taking .58s after using rem and quot it reduced to .39s.

Comment: That's good. But pray tell, have you the pragmas in your code?

Comment: @DanielFischer No I have not. How to do that can you give any simple example or code.[I am novice in Haskell]

Comment: Just put the line `{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}` as the first line of your code, and `{-# OPTIONS_GHC -O2 #-}` as the second line, the code you have (with the bang on the `!c = a + b` binding) after that.

Comment: This probably won't help with the speed, but note that you can make the code a lot simpler by making a (bogus) `Num` instance for your pairs (supporting only multiplication) and then using `^` to get fast exponentiation for free. If the numbers being given to you are small enough, you should use `Int` or `Word` (from `Data.Word`) for all your calculations, instead of accepting the `Integer` default. You'll need to add type signatures to some functions to do that.

Comment: @DanielFischer that is an answer, please post it as such to allow voting on it

Comment: @dfeuer Or implement `Semigroup`/`Monoid` and use [`stimes`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/semigroups-0.18.1/docs/Data-Semigroup.html#v:stimes) or `stimesMonoid`.

Comment: @PetrPudlák, indeed, those are more appropriate. I didn't know about them when I wrote the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, make sure to add type signatures and use the appropriate number type. All your numbers are fine with `Int`, since they're bounded by

```
2 * (1000000006 * 1000000006)
```

Therefore, you can get rid of `Integer` throughout your program and simply use `Int`:

```
fib2 :: Int -> (Int, Int)
fib2 0 = (1, 1)
fib2 1 = (1, 2)
fib2 n
 | even n    = ((a*a + b*b)`rem` 1000000007, (c*c - a*a)`rem` 1000000007)
 | otherwise = ((c*c - a*a)`rem` 1000000007, (b*b + c*c)`rem` 1000000007)
 where (a,b) = fib2 (n `quot` 2 - 1)
       c     = a + b
```

Next, you want to use `rem` and `quot`, since they're usually faster and provide the same result as `mod` and `div` on positive numbers.

We also add a type signature to `solve`:

```
solve :: Int -> Int
solve n = (a*b)`rem`1000000007
    where (a,b) = fib2((2*n-1)`rem`2000000016)
```

Last but not least, we now simplify your `main`:

```
main :: IO ()
main = C.getContents >>= putStrLn . unlines . map (show.solve. fst . fromJust . C.readInt) . tail . C.words
```

However, I don't think that the IO part is the bottle-neck, so your usual `String` methods should be fine for this challenge, e.g.

```
main = getContents >>= putStrLn . unlines . map (show . solve . read) . tail . words
```

Indeed, this version of your program gets accepted of SPOJ. But so did your one. I guess that they updated the GHC version* and used the appropriate optimization flags. But you can make sure that they use optimization via

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -O2 #-}
```

<sub>* I just rememered that [there was a defect with `even` in GHC 7.10](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35941674/1139697). If they used GHC 7.10 (which is [unlikely](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/download_ghc_7_10_1)), then you were affected by that defect.</sub>